# How to set the number of lines in uitextfield dynamically?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Actually i am trying to set the text in the textfield in next line when it becomes larger in the first line ad default. Can you please help me. my uitextfield is taken through the IB. and i am trying to write it and wants to post something like comment.

```
[viewFeedback setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_Feedback.png"]]];

CGSize size = [txtFeedback.text sizeWithFont:txtFeedback.font];
CGRect f = txtFeedback.frame;
f.size.height = ceil(size.width/f.size.width)*size.height;
txtFeedback.frame = f;
```

txtFeedback is the textfield name here..

Answer (score 0):

Well this would be a Increasing the height of the `UITextfield` dynamically. Please follow this or add your custom frame

In your `UITextViewDelegate` implementation of `textViewDidChange:` you need to calculate the size of the text for the specific width and adjust accordingly.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = [textView text];
    NSFont *font = [textView font];
    CGFloat width = [textView frame].size.width;

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    /* Adjust text view width with "size.height" */
}
```